# Does Morita theory hint higher modules for noncommutative ring?

Tags: higher-category-theory, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-rings, morita-equivalence, morita-theory

Two possibly noncommutative rings are called Morita equivalent if their left-module categories are equivalent. In the commutative case, Morita equivalence is nothing more than ring isomorphism. Otherwise, there are many known examples where this does not hold.

That means modules alone are not enough to characterize the ring. Are there notions of higher modules or higher structures, such that the corresponding higher Morita equivalence is nothing more than ring isomorphism?

**In short**, can you find a better notion of modules that faithfully capture their underlying ring?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Pointed category? That is, specify a specific free module on one generator.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes. The trick is to use not just categories, but *pointed categories*, which are categories equipped with a choice of object (the "pointing"). Given any ring $R$, the category $\mathrm{Mod}(R)$ is naturally pointed by the rank-1 free module, i.e. $R$-as-an-$R$-module, which I will write as $R_R$. Then it is almost trivial that the pointed category $(\mathrm{Mod}(R),R_R)$, up to equivalence, recovers $R$ up to isomorphism.

What's that? I didn't tell you what the morphisms are between pointed categories, so you don't what the equivalences are? Well, you do actually know what the equivalences are: an equivalence of pointed categories $(\mathcal{C},C) \simeq (\mathcal{D},D)$ is an equivalence of categories $F : \mathcal{C} \overset\sim\to \mathcal{D}$ together with an isomorphism $f : FC \cong D$. I mean, what else could it be? Anything else wouldn't justify the name. But there is actually an interesting question of what are the morphisms which are not equivalences. Surely, a morphism $(\mathcal{C},C) \to (\mathcal{D},D)$ should consist of a functor $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ together with a morphism $f$ between $FC$ and $D$. The interesting question is whether $f$ should be: (1) an isomorphism; (2) a morphism $f : FC \to D$; (3) a morphism $f : D \to FC$. These three options have names: (1) is called a *strong pointed functor*; (2) is called an *oplax pointed functor*; and (3) is called a *lax pointed functor*. It is almost trivial to show that all three options give the same notion of *equivalence* of pointed categories, but they give different bicategories of pointed categories (and this difference matters in applications).

An advantage of working with pointed categories is that there are plenty of pointed categories which share with $(\mathrm{Mod}(R), R_R)$ some of its nice structural properties, but not all, and so are not of that form.

Comment: Well.. this is slightly not what I expected.. since including $R_R$ in the data somehow uses the ring structure of $R$ directly.. and so no wonder it captures the ring structure :P But still thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: There's a further trick if you want to avoid explicitly using the ring structure of $R$ directly: instead of remembering the object $R_R$, you remember the forgetful functor $\mathbf{Mod} (R) \to \mathbf{Set}$. Of course, this amounts to remembering $R_R$ because it is the representing object for the forgetful functor...

Comment: This ought to work out to be a special case of a more general construction where an $E_n$-algebra can be recovered from the $E_{n-1}$-algebra structure on its category of modules, specialized to $n=0$ (an $E_0$-algebra is a pointed object).

Comment: Thanks for all your comments! I'm aware that my question is not clear enough, and perhaps cannot be made precise. What I'm really hoping is a description of modules that is *"implicit enough"* and can recover the ring. Of course, this is highly subjective, so perhaps I should ask a slightly more concrete question: What kind of rings have that "Morita=Classical"? .. and try to see how it fails for the others. Alas, this isn't what I really hope for.. it's just an approximation.

Comment: @Student any ring is Morita equivalent to all its matrix rings, but a ring is seldom isomorphic to any of its matrix rings.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes.

Comment: @Student Yes, of course it is simply "using" the ring structure. Maybe if I had called it "$1_R$" rather than "$R_R$" you would have liked it better :) Seriously, if your goal is something that *functorially* recovers $R$ and works for all rings, then you will have to "use" the ring structure.

Comment: Switching to pointed categories is not trivial, though. One thing people sometimes mean when they say "Morita" is the bicategory of algebras an bimodules. The (lax) pointed version of this is algebras and pointed bimodules --- this is the same as the bicategory of pointed categories abstractly equivalent to $\mathrm{Mod}(R)$, and lax pointed functors which preserve all colimits. Its groupoid of objects is the groupoid of rings, but it has a lot more morphisms, so it is somewhere between homomrphisms are Morita maps. It is explored e.g. in the paper of Gwilliam and Scheimbauer.

Comment: @ZhenLin one example I have in mind is the Tannakian reconstruction for (finite) groups, in which case one remembers the forgetful functor to (Vect). I never viewed that as a way to remember $\mathbb{C}[G]$. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Although I think my answer "pointed categories" is an important one, there is another way that the question could be interpreted: What is an interesting class of rings which are recoverable up to isomorphism from their categories of modules? And perhaps, if we are not trying to be too universal or functorial, we won't mind if the isomorphism is not unique.

For this, I *strongly* recommend Morita's original paper introducing his equivalences. (Kiiti Morita, Duality for modules and its applications to the theory of rings with minimum condition, Sci. Rep. Tokyo Kyoiku Daigaku, Sect. A 6, 83-142 (1958). You can find a PDF by googling.) Among the many things in that paper is a theorem saying that rings satisfying a natural minimality condition called "basic" are Morita equivalent iff they are isomorphic (commutative rings, I believe, satisfy this condition) and that every finite-dimensional ring is Morita equivalent to one satisfying this minimality condition. See [my answer to a related question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/225770/78).

Answer (score 0):

As explained for example here

https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/s3-72.2.281

the most direct analogue of Morita equivalence for (connected) graded algebras actually boils down to graded isomorphism.

However there are good reasons why one might actually want equivalence relations that are weaker than isomorphism: Morita, twisting (in the graded case, as in Zhang's work above), derived, and so on.  Making some broad classification feasible, for example; this is what noncommutative geometry seeks to do via the point scheme of Artin-Tate-van den Bergh, for example.